# Texturing a geometry using WebGL shader

Tags: shader, webgl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, 3d-rendering

I'm new to texturing and shading in WebGL. The problem is I want to color a sphere with a gradient color but when I use `gl_FragColor = vec4(vUv, 0.0, 1.);` There is a line on the surface
[image: Shere geometry with vUv].

After that, I use the position from the vertex shader `gl_FragColor = vec4(vPosition, 1.);` and get the result of 8 different colors which is not what I want.
[image: sphere geometry with position]

I think the problem is the position from the vertex shader is not passing correctly. Is there any way to solve this?

Fragment:

```
varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec3 vPosition;

void main () {
  vUv = uv;
  vPosition = position;
  gl_FragColor = vec4(vUv, 0.0, 1.);
  gl_FragColor = vec4(vPosition, 1.);
}
```

Vertex:

```
varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec3 vPosition;

void main () {
  vUv = uv;
  vPosition = position;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0); 
}
```

[Edit] After try `gl_FragColor = vec4(abs(vUv.x*2.0-1.0), vUv.y, 0.0, 1.0);`

from @Rabbid76
I got [The peak at top and bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEcqC.png)

Comment: *" think the problem is the position from the vertex shader is not passing correctly.[...]"* - Of course it is passed correctly. However, there is a transition from 0 to 1 this is what you can see in when the color changes from yellow to green. Yellow is (1, 1, 0) and green is (0, 1,0). The u-coordinate is 0.0 at 0° and 1.0 at 360°.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I see. I use the position to avoid the transition line but somehow it not working correctly.

Comment: Both coordinates look fine, if you have a seamless *texture* then the UV seam will not be visible. I think what you want is to add a sampler to your shader and read from it `gl_FragColor=texture2D(myTexture,vUv)`.

Comment: Try `gl_FragColor = vec4(abs(vUv.x*2.0-1.0), vUv.y, 0.0, 1.0);`

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank you, It does solve my problem but there is a peak that appears at the top and bottom.  It is better if it is a smooth geometry.